# where is title of material app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I read on stackoverflow that the title of `MaterialApp()` widget appears when we open recent apps screen.

I've provided `title` property on `MaterialApp` but I can't see my app title on Recent Apps Screen.

Comment: What does this mean "But still materialApp() title is not found." Where is it not found? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I guess the title of the MaterialApp widget is not visible on the recent apps screen.  @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I not get any error message. The only thing is that I want to know where is the MaterialApp() title is located in app. When I run my application I not saw the MaterialApp() title anywhere in my app.

Answer (score -1):

If you're testing your app on **Android Pie** then click on **Icon of app** from top in recent menu, there you'll see the title you set for `MaterialApp`

[image]

**Demo Gif**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tirth Patel for replying to my query. But the problem is not solved completely. I follow the steps as show in your gif, I get the project name when I click on flutter icon in recent apps. In short, I get my "project_name" written in place of "business card" written in your gif. I also want you to notify that I am not using Android Pie.

Comment: Which Android version are you using? & Please add some code to your question.